# Expresión regular que coincida también con mayúsculas

Tags: c#, regex

Saludos, tengo un problema al adaptar una expresion regular a C#, utilicé [esta página](http://regexpre.orgfree.com/) para armar mi expresion regular.

El objetivo de la expresión regular es la validación de correos electrónicos que cumplan con el estándar y también acepte los nuevos estándares de hotmail y outlook.

Armé la expresión regular y es la siguiente:

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$
```

El problema está en que al ponerla en c# no me lo valida correctamente, el bloque de código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
public bool ValidarEmail(String email)
        {
            String expresion;                
            expresion = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$";


            if (Regex.IsMatch(email, expresion))
            {
                if (Regex.Replace(email, expresion, String.Empty).Length == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

La expresión coincide con:

```
tucorreo-@hotmail.com
tucorreo_@hotmail.com
tucorreo_._@hotmail.com
```

Pero el sistema por default manda el parámetro `correo` en mayúsculas, y **no coincide con**:

```
TUCORREO@hotmail.com
```

¿Alguna idea de que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Cuales son los casos que no te validan correctamente, revisando tu regex me funciona sin ningun problema para los casos que pusiste asi como para otros que puese al azar, Saludos

Comment: Hola que tal, me funciona al calar la regex en la pagina, sin embargo en la aplicacion de c# cuando mando llamar la funcion me manda que el correo es incorrecto.

Comment: Asegurate de que el parametro que mandas a ValidarEmail no contenga espacio al principio o al final, por ejemplo: ValidarEmail(parametro.Trim()); de lo contrario es correcto que el regex detecte el correo como no valido mas los puntos a corregir en el regex mencionados por @Mariano especialmente con las mayusculas

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, implemente la función trim al mandar el parámetro, ya encontré mi problema, no era problema en el código si no lo que menciono @Mariano mi expresión regular no acepta mayúsculas y el sistema por default manda el parámetro: correo en mayúsculas, muchas gracias por su tiempo y paciencia.

Comment: Para probar expresiones regulares de .net online, quizás te interese revisar también: http://regexhero.net/tester/, http://www.regexplanet.com/ o http://refiddle.com/ ... Más herramientas en http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Deberías escapar todos los puntos. Los siguientes [metacaracteres](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) tienen un significado especial en regex:

   ```
   \   ^   $   .   |   ?   *   +   (   )   [   {
   ```

   Para tomarlos como literales, se deben escapar con una `\`. Quedaría:

   ```cs
   expresion = @"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";
   ```

2. Se debería permitir mayúsculas, utilizando el modificador:

   ```cs
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
   ```

**Código:**

```cs
public static bool ValidarEmail(String email)
{
    String expresion = @"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";

    return Regex.IsMatch(email, expresion, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/xD6xmH

> **Nota:** Esta expresión regular no coincide con todos los emails válidos, sólo con los que el autor de la pregunta quiso permitir. Por ejemplo, no se están permitiendo otros caracteres válidos como `+`, ni TLDs con más de 4 caracteres.

Comment: Ya funciono perfectamente! muchas gracias por la ayuda y por tu tiempo!

Comment: Mariano, sos un capo :D